# PHP's "use" keyword not properly including

Tags: php, yii

I am currently refactoring a project which has been halfheartedly ported to Yii. There are some classes in the components folder which are included in a controller with the PHP "use"-keyword. This gives me a "include(protected/components/classes/SClass.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory" error though.

What's really strange about it is, that changing the name (used by "use") to a non-existent file gives me a fatal error. Any ideas?

Comment: As SDC alludes to, Yii does have autoloading.  See [this article](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/165/understanding-autoloading-helper-classes-and-helper-functions/) for details.  You shouldn't need to manually included anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `use` keyword by itself in PHP does not do any including of other files. It merely tells PHP that the namespace defined in the `use` statement may be referenced by code further down in the current PHP file.

However, what is likely happening here is that your system has an `autoload` function defined. If there is an `autoload` function, PHP will call this function whenever it encounters a class name that it doesn't recognise. The `autoload` function searches for the class file to load and includes it if it can find it. This is probably where your errors are occurring.

In the first case, this is the sequence of events:

- the `use` statement is referencing a valid namespace, but this is ignored until a class in that namespace is referenced in the code.
- When the class is referenced, PHP says "I don't know this class yet, lets autoload it".
- The autoloader function is run, and builds a path to include. This usually comes from the namespace and classname of the class, but can be whatever the autoload function is written to expect.
- In this case, it sounds like the autoloader is building the path and running `include()` on that path, but the class doesn't exist where the autoloader expects. Hence the "file not found" error.

In the second case, where you change the `use` statement:

- The `use` statement now references a different namespace, but you probably haven't changed the code later in the program that actually references the class.
- The program reaches the code that calls the class, but it doesn't recognise the namespace because it doesn't match the `use` statement any more, so instant fatal error.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer explained a lot of bits and pieces I was missing from the bigger picture.

I still don't get why it the inclusion won't work, since the path it shows me in the include message is 100% correct. But with your answer I can make better research now and as soon as I find my answer I will accept it!

Comment: The problem in the include is likely to be related to the fact that the path quoted doesn't include a leading slash, so it's a relative path. This may not be relative to where you think it should be, which is probably what is breaking the include despite it looking right. Again, it will be in the autoload function that you need to be looking for this.

Comment: It does indeed work with an absolute path. I can't really wrap my head around which path it would need at that point since the current path looks as right as it gets to me.
Also I would really like not using the "use" keyword since Yii has its own importer, but it doesn't seem to be successful either and I don't know how to examine it. Same is true for autoload. Can you give me a hint how I could debug the autoload function?

Comment: Re not wanting to use `use`: The `use` keyword is part of PHP's namespace syntax. If you're using namespaces, you can't really avoid `use` (unless you want your code to be full of fully qualified namespace strings).

Comment: Re debugging the autoload function: Assuming you've found the autoload function in the first place (have you found it), it shouldn't be too hard to see what's going on with it, because they're generally pretty short bits of code. If you need to debug it, you can do so like any other function: either add `print` statements at strategic positions, or use a proper debugger like xDebug. But be aware that the autoloader will be called for every class that is referenced, so if your problem is not with the first class that is called, you might find you get swamped with debug messages.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear there: I'm fine with using "use" when I am using namespaces, but I would actually prefer just using the yii-native import function which gives me an overview over the imports which I don't have with namespaces.
BUT I am glad if I get it to work with namespaces, which is why I am now looking into inspecting the autoload...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the file ownership and permissions, and check for PHP security as is mentioned [HERE](http://www.karakas-online.de/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2235)

Comment: the whole folder is 777 and safe mode is off.